# Beautifulsoup/Selenium: Can't click on a button and fetch url using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a list of companies and their leads info from Linkedin Sales Navigator.
While I am able to scrape the company Names from the sales navigator, I am getting issues while scraping the leads info. For eg: If XYZ is a company and ABC, PQR, MNO are their leads, I am unable to scrape their info like: 'Name', 'Designation', 'Contact info'.

Previously, I was able to get the records extracted, but since, the sales navigator platform changed its structure- Previously,  Upon clicking on a lead it was opening a URL and from there I was able to get the records extracted. But now, The url is hidden and the profile of the lead, opens on the same page. After that, URL is visible.

I am trying to click on the lead and then open the url and scrape the necessary info.. but  it fails.

I tried introducing time.sleep in between other calls, but it didn't help much.
Here's my code for the same.

```
lead_links = []
button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('button--unstyled t-16 font-weight-600 nowrap-ellipsis')
for b in button:
    b.click()
    leads = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "artdeco-entity-lockup__title artdeco-entity-lockup__title--alt-link ember-view"})
    for lead in leads:
        lead_links.append(lead.a["href"])
        print(leads)
```

What am I missing here? Please help!

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: There's no error as such..but initially I had got a Nonetype error as no url was present in div tag..that Is how I got to know that they changed their design on the web.

Answer (score 0):

looks like issue is here

```
button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('button--unstyled t-16 font-weight-600 nowrap-ellipsis')
```

in selenium, class name do not have support for spaces, try changing it to css like below :

```
button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("button--unstyled.t-16.font-weight-600.nowrap-ellipsis")
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this as well, it didn't work.. There is list for Leads, and it should click each person(Lead) one by one..when it clicks a single lead, a new url is opened. info is scraped it again goes to the list and scrapes the second lead. This goes on till there is no lead.

Answer (score 0):

show me a snippet of this page source code
if you change the page or display another, you also need to change the reference to it, using the selenium webdriver library you can:

```
url2 = page1.current_url
```

then you can scrape the new page
it is also possible that the html document of a new page is opened in the current one (built-in module, you can reopen   in an existing one) but like I said, you would have to show the page code how it behaves and how it looks.